# issues installing selenium and chromedriver in the Anaconda Spyder environment

Tags: python, selenium, anaconda, selenium-chromedriver, spyder

I am trying ti setup selenium and chromedriver in the Ananconda spyder environment but keep hitting this following error:

```
dir_path = os,path.dirname(os.path.realpath(_file_))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-23-fdfb1f77b9dd>", line 1, in <module>
    dir_path = os,path.dirname(os.path.realpath(_file_))

NameError: name 'path' is not defined
```

The trouble is I am following a YouTube video step by step and it works with no issues on the demo, so not sure why I am getting this error.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You have a `,` instead of a `.` after `os` and before `path`. It should be: `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(_file_))`

Comment: Thanks Kevn K, that as a typo. I am now getting the following error

Comment: dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(_file_))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-24-36481cc8f3d1>", line 1, in <module>
    dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(_file_))

NameError: name '_file_' is not defined

Comment: Please edit the new error into your question as well as showing us what code or commands you used to get there...